# liferay 7 - how to change from the default liferay logo to the company logo?

Tags: liferay-7

Liferay 7 GA1 is just releasead but the documentation is not complete yet. How can I change from the default liferay's logo to the company logo? I want to have a custom logo for each site of course.

Answer (score 7):

1. Go into `Control Panel`->`Configuration`->`Instance Settings`->`Miscellaneous` tab and make sure `Allow site administrators to use their own logo?` checkbox is checked.
2. Now you can define a per site logo via: `your site in control panel`->`Navigation`->`Public Pages`->`Configuration` menu. Here `Logo` Tab appears now.

Answer (score 0):

For those using the 7.1 it's found at:

Build > Pages > Configure (cog icon) > Scroll down to bottom of page